Request Filter a Data Extension is using
I'm trying to retrieve the FilterDefinition a DataExtension is using but failing at it right now.
I'm able to retrieve the source of a Filter via the FilterDefinition SOAP call but that only gives me the DataExtension where a Filter is filtering on (=Source of the Filter). However I would like to know which Filters are being used by a DataExtension (=Destination of the Filter).
I see the FilterActivity has a FilterDefinitionID property which is what I need, however this is not retrievable via the FilterActivity SOAP call. I can get the Destination and Source ID via the FilterActivity SOAP call but not the Filter they are using.
Any suggestions on how I can link those Filters with the Destination Data Extensions?

It "should" work using FilterDefinitionID (that is the field to use to define the source DE when creating filters ). Could it be that the Data Extension you are filtering from is in Parent BU / Shared, while the filter is running in a Child BU? Then SOAP couldn't find the source DE without changing context to Parent.

Hi Jonas, I can retrieve the Data Extensions, however I can not get the FilterDefinitionID from the FilterActivity SOAP retrieve as this field is not retrievable, so I need to get that information from somewhere else. That way I can link the FilterDefinition with the DataExtension as a destination.  Not as a source cause I can fetch that data already in the FilterDefinition SOAP retrieve (DataSource.ObjectID in that request)
